# In unity, probuilder cube transform.position center is diff with normal cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

see my gif, I create probuilder cube and normal cube, set their transform.position to Vector.zero
[image]

how to make probuilder cube center same with normal cube?
[here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/probuilder-111418) is probuilder link

it's not only occurs in probuilder shape, my some prefab include child prefab also has this bug, how to make transform.position is always object center?

Comment: I don't use or know much about ProBuilder but there is a *"Center Pivot"* button in the ProBuilder tab from your screenshot...

Answer (score 2):

thanks @Programmer, I fix it with click probuilder > toolbar > "Center:Pivot"

[image]